VSCode Syntax Highlighting CSS/PHP mixed
I have a file style.php that contains css primarily and php in some areas. Syntax highlighting is completely broken in this scenario.
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
:root{
    --some-css-variable: <?php echo get_theme_mod("some_variable")?>
}

body{
    background: pink;
    .
    .
    .

}

I've tried a bunch of extensions and ancient forum post suggestions, but I cannot get vscode to recognise the php for what it is and the CSS for what it is.
I'm perfectly fine having to manually choose a language mode of (for instance) php+css, comment annotate that the outside is css, or whatever else - since it's not obvious that the non-php part is css. But I've found zero solutions, to what seems like a fairly common scenario.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

What about surrounding the styles with a style tag and remove them when a specific GET parameter is set? Since VS doesn't know that the content of the file should be text/css and the file extension is php all content is only rendered as PHP.

@1stthomas adding  does fix the syntax highlighting. But how would you go around removing them?

Add style tags around your style definitions and remove them on output. You can do it like following:
<?php if (false) { ?>
    <style>
<?php } ?>
    body {
        background: pink;
    }
<?php if (false) { ?>
    </style>
<?php } ?>

It's not that nice but it works on my own VSCode.

Haha that is definitely an ugly solution, but it works! Thanks
